# How do I prove that these sets are disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set.

Then, how do I prove that $S,S\times\{S\},\{S\cup(S\times\{S\})\}$ are mutually disjoint?

I know that $S$ and $S\times\{S\}$ are disjoint, but I'm not sure about the rest.. How do I prove it?

Comment: The last set only has 1 element: the set $S \cup (S \times \{S\})$. Can you show that this set is not an element of either of the first two?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would proceed.Take any pair of three sets,lets say first and last and prove that if something is element of one then it is not element of second.It may sound complicated so I will demonstrate.

Consider sets $S$ and $\{S \cup (S \times \{S\})\}$ .Since second one contains only one element by definition then we need to only prove that the named element does not belong to S.We can see that $S \cup (S \times \{S\})$ is not element of $S$ since $S$ is subset of it.

Now all you need to do is exhaust all possible choices,and show that they are all mutually disjoint